# Proper Ember.js resource route declaration

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to wrap my head around Ember resources but I'm hitting a wall. Looking at guides like [Rails + Ember.js](http://www.devmynd.com/blog/2013-3-rails-ember-js) I see the preffered way of declaring a resource route is:

```
EmberTester.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});
```

This seems very convoluted, having to create a nested resource to access the individual items. But besides the element of style, the real problem is the behavior: such a route, from what I can see in the serverside log and in the client side browser traffic monitoring evaluates the model hooks for both the 'posts' route and the 'post' route. That is, given the model hooks:

```
EmberTester.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return EmberTester.Post.find();
  }
});

EmberTester.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return EmberTester.Post.find(params.post_id);
  }
});
```

when visiting the url `/posts/1` *both* model hooks get executed, so the server is first asked for all posts and then for post_id:1. I must be missing the obvious, but I can't put my finger on it what is it.

Is there a simpler way to declare resources in Ember? Should I *not* declare resources and instead use plain routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesting in the router translates to nesting in your whole stack. If you like to have a list of posts on the left, then edit an individual post on the right hand side of your screen (as per the [Ember Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/)), then nesting will work for you. If you don't need that kind of behaviour you don't need to nest your routes at all. Nesting is perhaps more useful if you need related information like /posts/comments/  where you'd never find comments without some kind of post.

Also note, you should probably declare the Router as follows if you're not nesting:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('posts');
  this.route('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' }); 
});
```

Comment: I was missing the importance of aligning route nesting with view nesting. The `route('posts');route('post', {path:'/posts/:post_id');` approach is different in meaning from `resource('posts', function() {route('post', {path:':post_id'});});`. The first acts like a Rails resource (navigate from list to detail and back), but the later is the proper Ember resource for displaying on in the client the list and selected detail *simultaneously*.

Answer (score 2):

I created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/irurac/5/) to reproduce the issue you're talking about and changed the `router` code a bit:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' }); 
});
```

It does exactly the same thing as nested routes (I think, under the hood `post` is treated is nested).

When you navigate to `PostsRoute`, `model` hook of `PostsRoute` is fired. If you click on specific post, `PostRoute` `model` hook is not going to be fired.

However, if you go to a specific post and refresh the page, you'll notice that this time `PostRoute` `model` hook is fired.

You should use treat nouns as `resources` (posts, post, orders, etc) and verbs (adjectives) as `routes` (new, show, edit, etc.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 but I accepted @Gevious because he pointed to the importance of view nesting to align with route nesting.